# rpm2cpio skips files from RPM

Tags: centos, rpm, sssd

These steps are from a box running CentOS 6.5. I merely tried converting a RPM package to a CPIO archive and was surprised to find files listed in the RPM but absent from the archive. Here are the steps taken.

List out paths in the RPM:

```
$ rpm -qlp sssd-1.9.2-82.4.el6_4.x86_64.rpm | sort > rpm.lst
```

Convert the RPM to a CPIO archive:

```
$ rpm2cpio sssd-1.9.2-82.4.el6_4.x86_64.rpm > sssd-1.9.2-82.4.el6_4.x86_64.cpio
```

Save the list of files in the archive. The `sed` filter is required to remove leading dot entries from pathnames. This is not required for the RPM listing.

```
$ cpio -i -t < sssd-1.9.2-82.4.el6_4.x86_64.cpio | sed -e 's|^.||' | sort > cpio.lst
```

Finally, the diff showing missing files:

```
$ diff -u cpio.lst rpm.lst

--- cpio.lst        2015-07-16 19:54:06.020494348 +0530
+++ rpm.lst         2015-07-16 19:53:38.012494371 +0530
@@ -2,6 +2,7 @@
 /etc/rc.d/init.d/sssd
 /etc/rwtab.d/sssd
 /etc/sssd
+/etc/sssd/sssd.conf
 /usr/bin/sss_ssh_authorizedkeys
 /usr/bin/sss_ssh_knownhostsproxy
 /usr/lib64/ldb/modules/ldb/memberof.so
@@ -102,6 +103,8 @@
 /var/lib/sss
 /var/lib/sss/db
 /var/lib/sss/mc
+/var/lib/sss/mc/group
+/var/lib/sss/mc/passwd
 /var/lib/sss/pipes
 /var/lib/sss/pipes/private
 /var/lib/sss/pubconf
```

Why are there files present in the RPM but missing in the CPIO archive? My interest was especially in `/etc/sssd/sssd.conf` because I wanted to look at a sample config file. We are using a `sssd` package that is older then the one coming from [CentOS](http://vault.centos.org/6.5/updates/x86_64/Packages/). I repeated the steps above with the package from CentOS. The result was the same.

Comment: Interesting. All of those appear to be config files.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The entry for `sssd.conf` from the `sssd` spec file is:

```
%ghost %attr(0600,root,root) %config(noreplace) %{_sysconfdir}/sssd/sssd.conf
```

Quoting from [Maximum RPM](http://www.rpm.org/max-rpm-snapshot/s1-rpm-inside-files-list-directives.html) about the `%ghost` directive:

> By adding this directive to the line containing a file, RPM will know about the ghosted file, but will not add it to the package. However it still needs to be in the buildroot.

Therefore, `rpm2cpio` that is part of the same package as `rpm` skips ghost files when converting to a CPIO archive.

Answer (score 2):

Those files are empty files, therefore, they're not included into cpio archive, but are listed in rpm, even after you install rpm and if you'll check it with `rpm -V sssd` - it will have normal output, because it's listed in rpmdb that way, even when files are deleted, here is snippet from SRPM:
[image]

p.s. very interesting case!